# Find the interior $\{(x,y): 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$.

Tags: general-topology

> Find the interior $A = \{(x,y): 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$. I assume the metric is the standard Euclidean metric.

I know that the int$(A) = A$, but I don't know how to prove it. I can gather that the radius for any $x \in A$ should be $r = \min(\sqrt{x^2_1 + x_2^2},1 -\sqrt{x^2_1 + x_2^2})$ such that $B(x;r) \subseteq A$ by looking at a graph, but how do I show that this is true?

Comment: you can show that $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for a given norm e.g. $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$.

Comment: Pick some $(x_0,y_0) \in A$. What is the distance of this point to the origin or the edge of the unit disk? Is it positive? If so, can you find a smaller radius around the point so that the resulting disc is entirely contained in $A$?

Answer (score 1):

This works in any metric space. So you have a distance $d$ and the ball of radius $1$ around $x_0$.

Let $r=1-d(x_1,x_0)$. If $x$ is at distance less than $r$ from $x_1$, then by the triangle inequality
$$
d(x,x_0)\leq d(x,x_1)+d(x_1,x_0) < r + 1-r = 1. 
$$
In your example  $x_0=(0,0)$, $x_1= (x_1,x_2)$ and $d((a,b),(c,d))=\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

It will be easier to write if you think of the plane as the Argand plane.

So let $z_0$ be the affix of the point $M_0(x_0,y_0)$. The affix of a point in the open ball with centre $M_0$ and radius $r$ can be written as
$$z=z_o+u, \enspace \text{where } \;|u|<r.$$
Using the triangle inequality, can you show that, if $\; r<\min(|z_0|,1-|z_0|)$, then $\;0<|z|<1$?

Answer (score 0):

Your set is the inverse image of $(0,1)$ with respect to a continuous function (the distance from the origin). Since $(0,1)$ is an open set and the mentioned function is continuous, your set is open too.